# Program to find factorials for given test cases

Tags: c, factorial

Input
An integer t, 1<=t<=100, denoting the number of test cases, followed by t lines, each containing a single integer n, 1<=n<=100.

Output
For each integer n given at input, display a line with the value of n!

I have typed the code below and it doesn't get accepted on codechef.
I don't know why.

```
#include<stdio.h>
double fact(int n);
void disp(double t);

int main() {
  int a, i, c[100];
  scanf("%d", &a);
  for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &c[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    disp(fact(c[i]));
  }
  return 0;
}

double fact(int n) {
  double f;
  if (n == 1 || n == 0)
    f = (double) 1;
  else
    f = (double) n * fact(n - 1);
  return f;
}

void disp(double t) {
  printf("%f\n", t);
}
```

Comment: Is this a question about C or CodeChef?  Have you tried compiling and executing this program locally, using GCC for example?

Comment: how about a `uint64` instead of `double`?

Comment: Is this not accepted because of time out or because the answer was incorrect

Comment: Why doesn't the code "get accepted on CodeChef"? Are there error messages?

Comment: There are some inefficiencies, you use tail recursions which could easily be changed into a loop and you can implement a lookup table so that you are not recomputing factorials over and over again. If the error in integer overflow I recommend using python or something similar to avoid the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have typed the code below and it doesn't get accepted on codechef.
>   I don't know why.

OP's code fails as `double` lacks precision for this task. Given "containing a single integer n, 1<=n<=100." and `fact(100)`, the printed result needs far more precision than afforded by `double`.

---

100! is exactly

> 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000

`double` (precision) and `uint64_t` (range) are both insufficient for this task.  Need new approach.  Something that extends exact integer multiplication.

Perhaps create a function that multiplies a *string*?  `mult_str(char *s, int n)`?  `"1"` * 2 --> `"2"`.

Do-able in about 30 lines of C code without special libraries.

Comment: If OP want to avoid the learning experience, simple enough to search for a coded solution - I will not add one here as OP did not ask for that.